# Integrating GitKit login into my project

Tags: android, facebook-login, google-signin, google-identity-toolkit

Im tring to put the activity i've taken from GitKit website and implement it in my code so i'll have a facebook and google login to my app.
I have the following dependency in my gradle:

```
compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-identitytoolkit:v3-rev206-1.21.0'
```

But i'm still getting an error when im tring to import:

```
import com.google.identitytoolkit.GitkitClient;
import com.google.identitytoolkit.GitkitUser;
import com.google.identitytoolkit.IdToken;
```

it says the they cannot be resolved.
How do i fix it?

Comment: Do you build your project ?

Comment: sure. i think that some dependency or jar or something is missing... @Sree

Comment: better you add `com.google.apis:google-api-services-identitytoolkit:v3-rev206-1.21.0` from project structure - dependency- library dependancy. If it exist it will work

Comment: nope... still the same error what should i do? @Sree

Comment: can you able to add that as a library dependency?

Comment: yes i've added it as a library but the error remains

Comment: can i able to show your dependencies?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31852548

Comment: YES!! it solved all the imports except for the    :
import com.google.identitytoolkit.IdToken
how do i add also that import?
     @Sree

Answer (score 0):

You may refer to the `build.gradle` file in the Google Identity Toolkit Android quickstart sample app: https://github.com/googlesamples/identity-toolkit-android/blob/master/tutorial/build.gradle